# jQuery, DataTables, KeyTables: Check checkbox with space key

Tags: jquery, dom, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a DataTable defined in my script.

```
var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
"lengthMenu": [ [15, 30, 45, 60, -1], [15, 30, 45, 60, "All"] ],
"orderMulti": true,
"stateSave": true,
"pagingType": "full_numbers",
"autoWidth": false,
"pageLength": 15,
"dom": '<C<f><i><l><B<"clear">><p>rt>',
buttons: [
    {
        extend:    'copyHtml5',
        text:      '<i class="fa fa-copy"></i>',
        titleAttr: 'Copy'
    },
    {
        extend:    'excelHtml5',
        text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-excel"></i>',
        titleAttr: 'Excel'
    },
    {
        extend:    'csvHtml5',
        text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-alt"></i>',
        titleAttr: 'CSV'
    },
    {
        extend:    'pdfHtml5',
        text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf"></i>',
        titleAttr: 'PDF'
    }
],
'keys': true
});
```

This works on a table with rows that look like so:

```
<tr>
    <td><input class="checkboxRun" data-run_id="1" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><a href="url here">2018-03-27T15:59:50.163000</a></td>
    <td><a href="url here">Name</a></td>
    <td><a >0:00:01.076000</a></td>
    <td><a >None</a></td>
    <td><a >No scores yet.</a></td>
</tr>
```

The first cell on each row, is a checkbox. I've been trying for a while to create a bit of script that will check (via .find('input:checkbox') I'm thinking) whether the cell you're on is a checkbox, and if so, allow `.prop('checked', this.checked);` with spacebar.

I don't seem to be able to get an actual DOM element with the API.

So far I got:

```
table.on( 'key-focus', function () {

    // The cell, returns an API object, but I don't know how to get the DOM
    // element from this API object
    var cell = table.cell( { focused: true });

    // The node, returns the actual TD, seemingly as an object.
    // I can't seem to be able to do node.find('input'); though, it says
    // node.find is not a function, so I suspect it's not an actual DOM
    // element?
    var node = table.cell( { focused: true } ).node();

    // The data, returns raw HTML as a string
    var data = table.cell( { focused: true } ).data();

    // This doesn't work. Gives an error (node.find is not a function)
    console.log(node.find('input'));
});
```

For now I don't even have the spacebar key bits yet, I can't get past the hurdle of actually identifying whether the element is even a checkbox.

Comment: See [jQuery DataTables: How to navigate rows with KeyTable plug-in](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-navigate-rows-with-keytable-plugin/).

Comment: That page seems to have the same information as I do. He can get the data. The cell, the row, all as DataTable API objects. I tried it and I get the exact same behavior, I can't `.find('input');` on `table.row(cell.index().row);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(node).find('input')` to find `input` element, because `node` is a DOM element and `find()` is a jQuery method.

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/rbhhmqpw/68/) for demonstration.

See [jQuery DataTables: How to navigate rows with KeyTable plug-in](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-navigate-rows-with-keytable-plugin/) for more details.

Comment: I see my mistake now. It was very basic. Your example does exactly as needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: Would you happen to also know how to target only the cells that are currently "drawn" when I click the select all checkbox? Using your example right now, if I click on select all, it literally means all, even rows that are filtered out. [EDIT] Found my answer finally. Just needed to add `{ page: 'current' }` inside the rows() function for the click all selector.
Ends up like: 
`$('#checkAll').click(function() {
   $(':checkbox', table.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes()).prop('checked', this.checked);
  });`

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick: http://live.datatables.net/nijizuco/1/edit

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        keys: {
            keys: [32, "\t".charCodeAt(0)]
        }
    });

    table.on('key', function(e, datatable, key, cell, originalEvent) {
        if (key === 32) {
            if ($(cell.node()).find('input').hasClass('checkboxRun')) {
                var checkBox = $(cell.node()).find('input');
                checkBox.prop("checked", !checkBox.prop("checked"));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I combined both of your answers together.